# Joomla and anchor links with target="_blank"

Tags: html, joomla, module, anchor

Using a Custom HTML module and have the following code:

```
<h2><a href="mailto:info@studev.net" target="_blank">info@studev.net</a></h2>
```

However after saving the module, the rendered code becomes:

```
<h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var prefix = '&#109;a' + 'i&#108;' + '&#116;o';
var path = 'hr' + 'ef' + '=';
var addy61999 = '&#105;nf&#111;' + '&#64;';
addy61999 = addy61999 + 'st&#117;d&#101;v' + '&#46;' + 'n&#101;t';
var addy_text61999 = '&#105;nf&#111;' + '&#64;' + 'st&#117;d&#101;v' + '&#46;' + 'n&#101;t';
document.write('<a ' + path + '\'' + prefix + ':' + addy61999 + '\'>');
document.write(addy_text61999);
document.write('<\/a>');
//-->\n </script><a href="mailto:info@studev.net" style="">info@studev.net</a><script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write('<span style=\'display: none;\'>');
//-->
</script><span style="display: none;">This email address is being protected from spambots. You need JavaScript enabled to view it.
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write('</');
document.write('span>');
//-->
</script></span></h2>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 'Content - Email Cloaking' plugin for protection email in joomla. This plugin changes each email in such way (with js). If you want, you can disable this plugin. But If you found such code with js in source of page it is normal.
/libraries/joomla/html/html/email.php - rule for 'email cloaking'

Comment: Ah right, the problem is its removing the target="_blank" from the code stopping the link from opening in a new window. Is it safe to disable this plugin or a way to work around this?

Comment: This plugin helps to hide email on page from spambots ("Cloaks all emails in content from spambots using JavaScript"). You can disable target="_blank", when user click on email, all will work normal.
Regarding disabling of plugin. i always think, that if spamer needs in some email on your site, he will get it in any case )))

Comment: When you say disable target="_blank" what do you mean by disable it, remove it from the code? Because I really want that link to open in a new window. I could use Javascript to open the link in a new window or Javascript to add target="_blank" to the anchor link after the page is rendered, but I was just wandering if there was a way to stop it from being removing in the first place?

Comment: Why you open link with mailto in new window? My browser opens mail client for such links. Sorry, if do not know something.

Comment: If people are using Google Chrome with a Gmail account, it will open up Gmail however in the same window, I've just gotten used to the practice of putting target="_blank" in mailto links as I use Gmail myself. Ill try adding the target="_blank" post page load. Ill check your answer as it does solve the problem and was very helpful identifying that plugin as I had no idea it was that plugin changing the rendered code. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for description about gmail (i did not know about it). You can also improve this plugin or create new. /plugins/content/emailcloak/emailcloak.php

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to add attributes to anchors that are filtered by the Email Cloaking plugin, you can use this piece of jQuery to add your own attributes after the page has loaded:

HTML Example:

```
<h2 id="contactUsEmail"><a href="mailto:info@studev.net" target="_blank">info@studev.net</a></h2>
```

You cannot put the ID in the anchor tag as the plugin removes this as it renders the page, so use the parent tags and then use ">" to identify a child element, in this case an anchor tag, as so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contactUsEmail > a").attr("target","_blank");
});
```

This target="_blank" to the anchor link, after the page has loaded, but keeping the Email Cloaking plugin still enabled